# React Route - On click check if user is logged in, if not, send him to login and then back to page

Tags: reactjs, redirect, routes

What I have at the moment:

1. User checks out leaderboard with a list of players.
2. User clicks on player card inside the leaderboard.
3. I check if User is logged in, if User is not logged in, I send him
   to    the Log In page.

What I desire.

1. User checks out leaderboard with a list of players.
2. User clicks on player card inside the leaderboard.
3. I check if User is logged in, if User is not logged in, I send him
   to    the Log In page, after he logs in, I send him back to the player profile he clicked earlier.

I literally have no idea how and where should I look for this.

Comment: Can you please include some code showing us what you have already tried.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create an example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are using any routers as you didn't specify that.
But what you need is called "Guarded Route" or "Route Guard".

A guard is a "check" or "condition" which will allow the user to visit a specified route or not.

Let me give you an example with React-Router.
https://codepen.io/najt/pen/jOBjOMW

in short you can do something like this:

```
const GuardedRoute = ({loggedIn, ...props}) => {
  if (loggedIn) {
    return <Route {...props} />;
  }
  return <Redirect to="/login" />
}
```

In a normal flow you should not allow someone to choose a profile if he is not logged in. And make sure that he has access to the selection only if he has already logged in. This is more UX (User Experience) than code but worth mentioning i think.

But if you really need the functionality you can look into "History" related to React-Router-Dom. It gives you the ability to retrieve the history of accessed URI and redirect back the user back to the page he tried to access.

Another possibility is redirect him onto Login with a param in the url `&redirect=/profile/example` and use this param during Login action.

With:

- React@17
- React-Router-Dom@5

Comment: This guided me on the right path, thank you! :)

The project is too big to be able to put any code samples, I mean, I could, but would make the question 10x more complex. In app.js we have our router with lots of conditions, I have managed to do it.